# css font family issue in chrome

Tags: css

[image]

Hello,i have a problem regarding font-family in chrome. I used Merriweather font but it looks good in Mozilla but in chrome it looks like see in below image mostly it doesn't support characters like B,g,t check in around red circle, i also used -web-kit for chrome and all but i didn't get proper response, so please help me how can i resolve it.

Comment: Welcome, please post up relevant code for us to help us with. This is, after all, a website dedicated to coding questions.

Comment: please check  https://jsfiddle.net/pkwd/w5169wrm/1/

Comment: Are there any other CSS rules being applied to these fonts?  It's kind of weird that a Google font wouldn't render correctly in Chrome.

Comment: no, its only Merriweather.